Is there an annotation converter from Bookari (Mantano) to Moon+ Reader?
I recently change my old tablet with Android 10 for a new one with Android 14. In the old one I have a lot of ebooks (epub and pdf) which I read with Bookari 4.2.4 and I have a lot of notes in them.
However, I can't install the Bookari app because it is no longer supported. So, I decided to go with the Moon+ Reader app.
The relevant question is: Is there any way to convert the annotations?
Bookari save the information in the notes table of the mreader-premium.db database.
Moon+reader in the notes table of the mrbooks.db.
The problem is that each one uses a different positioning scheme that I am not able to identify and therefore I can't move the information from one database to another.
Any suggestions? Thanks
